# How to get a message from a controller "Spring MVC"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web, java-ee-7

I have a simple problem, but i couldn't resolve it. 
I want to get a simple message in my view (page) from a controller (PageController). Or, I want to start my application directly from my controller.

- This what i have as a code :
- Web.xml :

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> <!-- pour que tous les controlleurs passe par le fontcontroler it was = *.htm-->
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

- My dispatcher-servlet :

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.shopping.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!-- The index controller -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="page" />
```

- My page (view) :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Shopping</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Message</h1>
        ${message}
    </body>
</html>
```

- My Controller :

```
package com.mycompany.shopping.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})
    public ModelAndView index() {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("message", "welcome to MVC Spring Web 'Test'");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

and this is my project organization on netbeans 10 : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRvUe.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello Abid, could you show us the code that you have in your onStartup() method please?

Comment: Hello Terry, Ii don't have any onStartup() methode (it's a spring mvc web application)

Comment: Ah yes. So can you try to change <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> with <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> and add method = RequestMethod.GET to your @RequestMapping ?

Comment: thank you so much Terry. I found the solution. It was simple, i changed just this : 
     import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
to 
     import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
and it's working.